# Shut down theme stuck on Plasma 5.9.5

Tags: themes, shutdown, 17.04, customization, plymouth

I tried to personnalise my boot theme, and downloaded themes on internet, but it didn't work.
The problem is that now when i shut down my computer, the shut down theme is just a black screen with Plasma 5.9.5 wrote on it... Can you help? im a beginner and have ubuntu 17.04

Comment: How and why did you install Plasma on Ubuntu? If you want Plasma, do a clean install of **K**ubuntu.

Comment: i removed all plymouth themes and installed them again, it solved the problem. Thanks